# Can I use a Facebook app page as the support URL when submitting an iOS app?

Tags: ios, app-store

I can't find the answer to the question. Do I have to create a website or blog page? Can I use Facebook application page instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its not always necessary to create a website or blog . They will accept facebook page/google plus page as support url .